# Sharepoint connect 2.3 Managed Metadata field type value

Tags: sharepoint-connect

How can we read Managed Metadata field values from Sharepoint using Sharepoint Connect 2.3 module?

For Single Line fields type we used "ows_ColumnName", but this approach is not working for Managed Metadata fields.